# In an ant build script, can I reference a path in a different build file?

Tags: java, ant

I have a path with an id in one build file. I have another build file which requires a path containing the same jars that are defined in the first build file. Instead of duplicating the jars in the second build file, can I simply reference the path defined in the first build file from my second build file? I can't import the first build file using an import tag for various reasons. Are there any other options?

Comment: Could you define the path in a third file, and then import it into both the build files?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the path to the JARS as an environment variable, and look up those environment variables in your second build file.

I am not sure how you export environment variables from ant, but here's how you import them:

```
<property environment="ENV" />
<condition property="HOSTNAME" value="${ENV.TARGETHOSTNAME}">
    <isset property="ENV.TARGETHOSTNAME" />
</condition>
```

(TARGETHOSTNAME being the environment variable that was set previously)

Answer (score 0):

Option #1: put jar paths in a separated file, say, `jars.config` and load it to build files using:

```
<property file="jars.config"/>
```

Option #2, if are calling the second build file from the first one, you can define appropriate properties in the second build file, and specify them when you call it:

```
...
<ant ...>
  <property name="jar1.path" value="${jar1.path}"/>
  ...
</ant>
```